# Take all links from a paragraph and put them in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markup

**I have a paragraph:**

```
<p class="links">Lorem <a href="#">diam</a> nonummy nibh <a href="#">Lorem</a></p>
```

**And below that, I have a list:**

```
<ul class="list">

</ul>
```

**With jQuery, how can I do this:**

- Look for all `<a>` elements found in `<p class="links">`
- Display all `<a>`'s found inside said class
- Put all `<a>`'s in `<ul class="list">` and wrap all `<a>`'s in an `<li>`

Comment: if you want to use li element, change div class="list" to ul class="list"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

**edit:**

```
$("p.links a").clone().appendTo('.list').wrap('<li />');
```

---> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vQavd/1/)

Comment: nice, how can I make it so they don't move the a tags, but copy them?

Comment: `$(this).clone().wrap("<li>").appendTo(".list")`

Comment: I had switched the order of the appendTo and wrap function and it worked! Thanks

Comment: You can do it without the loop

Answer (score 2):

Kinda tired but

```
$('.links a').clone().appendTo('.list').wrap('<li>');
```

Does the job

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9RXY/

Answer (score 0):

Alex was close, but that solution selects each `<p>` with a class of links, and you want all the `<a>` inside the `<p>`, correct?

```
$("p.links a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<li>').appendTo(".list");
});
```